# Triangle Question

Tags: mesh, topology, geometry

I've noticed that in Object Mode, if you select an object it will tell you how many triangles are in the mesh. However, is there a way to highlight where they are? From what I can see, everything is made out of quads. It says the same thing for the default cube as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Triangle count refers to the tessellated result of the final mesh, required by graphics cards to draw geometry, not necessarily your mesh polygons.

A four sided face will be made up of two triangles, even though no three sided faces are present in your model.

[image]

To find all three sided faces faces in one mesh, while in *Edit Mode* select one of the triangles, the use the *Select Similar* operator <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> > *Polygon Sides*.

[image]

Or If one can't easily be found, do the inverse process, select a quad, then invert selection with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>.